# XML Schema: Are extensions part of the identifier uniqueness space

Tags: xml, xsd

Let's say I declare a type A, and then declare another type B that inherits from A by extension. Similarly, I also create a type C that inherits from A.
Let's say that A has an attribute "att", and that I create a key such that the value of "att" is unique and can be used to reference objects of type A.

How are objects of type B and C affected by that? Can I use this method such that B and C share an identifier space without being the same type?

You might tell me that I can use the selector of the key to specify both B and C. But what if instead of B and C I have hundreds of different types that need to share an ID space? In this case, I would need such a property inheritance method...

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Identity constraints are declared on elements, not types; they use a rather small subset of XPath to identify the keys and/or unique values they constrain.

So how simple or complicated it will be to make the uniqueness constraint affect elements with complex types A, B, and C (or A, B001, B002, ... B999, C001, C002, ... C999) depends on what names those elements have, whether they appear at consistent depths in the tree, whether the attribute in question always has the same name, and who knows what all else.

In the simple case, the constraint may look as simple as this:

```
<unique name="A-uniqueness">
  <selector xpath=".//A"/>
  <field xpath="@A-unique-ID"/>
</unique>
```

Or this:

```
<unique name="A-uniqueness-2">
  <selector xpath=".//*"/>
  <field xpath="@A-unique-ID"/>
</unique>
```

There are of course plenty of opportunities for complication.

Comment: If I define a type that contains an element that itself contains an attribute ID. If I add a uniqueness constrains to this ID. Now I create another type that derives from the previous one. Will the uniqueness constraint also be applied to that new type? and under the sape ID space as the original type?

Comment: Uniqueness constraints are applied to the items in the input instance identified by the `selector` and `field` information in the constraints' declarations; the XPaths for selectors and fields select items by name, not by type.  But you seem to be imagining an attribute A on an element E declared local to a type T; neither extension nor restriction of T can change the names of E or A, so it could be difficult to write the selectors on a uniqueness constraint in such a way that they applied  in instance of T but not in instances of types derived from T.